# *ngIf/else not working Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-template

I'm having trouble getting using *ngIf/else statements to work. Here is the setup:

```
<div *ngFor="let sub of day">
   <p>{{ sub.subject }}</p>
   <button type="button" *ngIf="sub.subject; else showElse" routerLink="/day" (click)="viewIndividual(day)" class="btn btn-{{colors[i]}}">View {{ daysBetween[i] | date:'EEEE' }}'s Plan</button>
   <ng-template #showElse>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add a Lesson</a>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

The issue is my truthy statement is rendering (the button with `View {{ daysBetween[i] | date:'EEEE' }}'s Plan`) on it, but my falsy value (the `ng-template`) is not. I've looked at a couple tutorials and I thought I am doing it right, but I've only been studying Angular4 for a few days now. Please help!

Comment: It works well for me https://plnkr.co/edit/2yaERj7RUJBGipOJrxSE?p=preview

Comment: Hmm yeah...thanks! I think I am getting something messed up here. I want either the "Add a Lesson" button or "View Plan" to show...

Comment: What is sub.subject exactly? Because you are asking your if statement whether there is a value in sub.subject, so unless your subject is changed to become equal to 0, null or false, it will always be true. Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://plnkr.co/edit/3h3UofVnVa7jKvbR1rdw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a `ngSwitch` or, as you only have two cases, go directly for two `ngIf`:

```
<div *ngFor="let sub of day">
   <p>{{ sub.subject }}</p>
   <button *ngIf="sub.subject" type="button" routerLink="/day" (click)="viewIndividual(day)" class="btn btn-{{colors[i]}}">View {{ daysBetween[i] | date:'EEEE' }}'s Plan</button>
   <a *ngIf="!sub.subject" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add a Lesson</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your ***ngIf** condition once again. 
I have tried same in my code it is working.

```
TestObj = [
            {
                category : 'Test'
            }, {
                category : 'Test1'
            }
        ]
```

HTML Code :

```
<div *ngFor="let key of TestObj">
    <p *ngIf="key.subcategory; else newText">** {{key.category}}</p>
       <ng-template #newText>No category found</ng-template>
</div>
```

This is showing `No category found` two times because of the condition.

**Note :** 
If you want to simplify condition you can do by checking subject condition in component and set flag true or false according to that. And use that flag in ***ngIf**.